# Download files using php after showing download page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a file to be downloaded via PHP (To allow only logged in users to be able to download).The download page has same rating and comment system to be shown but the file download immediately starts without showing the download page.How can i fix this?

```
<?php

require("usercheck.php");
$file = 'D:\dd.pdf';


if (file_exists($file)) 

{

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width">

    <title>Download</title>

    <?php require("headfiles.php");?>
    <link href="star/star-rating.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="star/star-rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

----------------------Body contents----------------
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work now because you're loading the file on top of the download page.
I would move the PHP above the html page header into a separate file and link to it from the Download page. If you wanted the download to begin immediately from the Download page, you could force the download using JavaScript. Don't forget to use the authentication check on both the download page and the file.